# Unable to apply style using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using following code to generate PDF using .iTextSharp version 5.4.3.

```
// Create a Document object
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);

        // Create a new PdfWriter object, specifying the output stream
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

        // Open the Document for writing
        document.Open();

string data = @"<table cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:30px;;">
         <tr>
             <td></td><td>Visit</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th>Datw</th><td>07/01/2013</td><td>07/18/2013</td><td>07/17/2013</td><td>07/09/2013</td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th>Score</th><td>3.00</td><td>6.33</td><td>1.00</td><td>8.00</td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th>Heading</th><td>7.0</td><td>8.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>3.0</td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th>Minutes</th><td>88</td><td>n/a</td><td>22</td><td>n/a</td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th>Test Data</th><td>5.0</td><td>8.0</td><td>4.0</td><td>3.0</td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th>Status</th><td>8.0</td><td>8.0</td><td>3.0</td><td>3.0</td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th>Data </th><td>3.96</td><td>6.88</td><td>5.83</td><td>6.67</td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th>Assessment (0-10)</th><td>5.0</td><td>3.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>2.0</td>
        </tr><tr>
             <th class="seperator">With heading</th><td>n/a</td><td>n/a</td><td>n/a</td><td>n/a</td>
        </tr>
    </table>";



        IElement ele;
        PdfPTable t;
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
        styles.LoadStyle("seperator", "border-top", "#a9a9a9 2px solid");

        List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(data), styles);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            ele = htmlarraylist[k];

            document.Add(ele);
            //document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }


        document.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Receipt-test.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
```

While its generating PDF, its not applying styling. Also its not showing  tags in bold.

Am I missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You're using `HTMLWorker`, an obsolete class that is no longer supported. It doesn't support CSS files and that explains why all questions about iText, HTML and CSS remain unanswered. You should use *XML Worker* instead of the `HTMLWorker` class. See http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker and http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code. I've tested and it applied all styles:

```
class Program
{
    private static void createPDF(string html)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);

        HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);

        document.Open();
        worker.StartDocument();

        worker.Parse(reader);

        worker.EndDocument();
        worker.Close();
        document.Close();

        fs.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = @"<table cellspacing='0' border='0' style='border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:30px;color:red;'>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td><td>Visit</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th>Datw</th><td>07/01/2013</td><td>07/18/2013</td><td>07/17/2013</td><td>07/09/2013</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th>Score</th><td>3.00</td><td>6.33</td><td>1.00</td><td>8.00</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th>Heading</th><td>7.0</td><td>8.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>3.0</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th>Minutes</th><td>88</td><td>n/a</td><td>22</td><td>n/a</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th>Test Data</th><td>5.0</td><td>8.0</td><td>4.0</td><td>3.0</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th>Status</th><td>8.0</td><td>8.0</td><td>3.0</td><td>3.0</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th>Data </th><td>3.96</td><td>6.88</td><td>5.83</td><td>6.67</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th>Assessment (0-10)</th><td>5.0</td><td>3.0</td><td>2.0</td><td>2.0</td>
                    </tr><tr>
                            <th class='seperator'>With heading</th><td>n/a</td><td>n/a</td><td>n/a</td><td>n/a</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>";

        createPDF(data);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you quick reply and adding an example. I have following problems: 1) Its not showing the data in <TH> tags in bold, which is normally the case with an HTML table. 2) The last <TH> tag is having a class by the name 'seperator', this class adds border at the top of the cell, this class is not applied. Can you please verify it again.

Comment: Yes, *th* doesn't take bold by default in iTextsharp. You can apply bold specially using *style='font-weight:bold;'*. Regarding separator it doesn't work because you have specified *border='0'*. Remove that and you should be good to go.

Comment: I can understand about 'th' tag but even after removing border from the table, I am not seeing the style being applied. Also, in your code you are not telling explicitly to include/apply the styling.

Comment: hmmm StyleSheet don't work many of the times. I think it is not properly implemented in PDFSharp. Instead try specifying inline CSS directly and it would work.